# Search dialog box doesn't shows up

Tags: android

I tried to follow the developers guide line and checked the error that are similar to this my manifest and searchable file looks ok but still search dialog box doesn't appears. Any help is appreciated thanks in advance.

**ser.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:hint="@string/hint">
</searchable>
```

**manifest.xml**

```
<activity
            android:name="e.ftsexample.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTop" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.searchable"
                android:resource="@xml/ser" />
        </activity>
```

**Mainactivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    DbS cr;
    private String[] from;
    private int[] to;
    private SimpleCursorAdapter str;
    private ListView LS;
    SQLiteDatabase ss;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        cr = new DbS(getApplicationContext());
        setDefaultKeyMode(DEFAULT_KEYS_SEARCH_LOCAL);
        GetMysearch(getIntent());
        // views
        LS = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        from = new String[] { DbS.Name_Col, DbS.Number_col };
        to = new int[] { R.id.sV, R.id.sVS };
        ss = cr.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor currr = ss.query(DbS.Table_Name, new String[] { " rowid _id ",
                DbS.Name_Col, DbS.Number_col }, null, null, null, null, null);

        str = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.qss, currr, from, to, 0);

        LS.setAdapter(str);
    }

    private void GetMysearch(Intent myint) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Intent myint = getIntent();
        if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(myint.getAction())) {
            String query = myint.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
            Log.e("Reached", "intent");
            doMySearch(query);
        }
    }

    private void doMySearch(String query) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "QUERY REACHED",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSearchRequested() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onSearchRequested",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return super.onSearchRequested();

    }


    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Intet passed",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        setIntent(intent);
        GetMysearch(intent);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding this to your activity:

```
<meta-data
android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
android:value="e.ftsexample.MainActivity" />
```

**Edit:** The reason is that you configured your activity to receive search query, but not to initiate a search.you can add this to any other activity and start search by callin 
            `onSearchRequested();`

hope this help.

Comment: ahh, it's obvious you are not calling onSearchRequested() any where you have just override it. for the instance just add "onSearchRequested();" after "LS.setAdapter(str);" and see what happens.

Comment: thanks Tarek it works. but the dialog appears as soon the activity starts how to start it when clicked on edittext

Comment: set an OnClickListener to that edit text, and in the onClick method call the onSearchRequested();